# Take single element from html. AngleSharp + htmlParsing xamarin

Tags: xamarin, anglesharp

Hello sorry my bad english!

i want to take book-title, author-name, book-description and ISBN code by entering id page - [sample page](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/145346364/)

I can take book-title because it single element:

```
class OzonParser : IParser<string[]>
{

    public string[] Parse(IHtmlDocument document)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        var title = document.QuerySelectorAll("h1").Where(item => item.ClassName != null && item.ClassName.Contains("bItemName")).First();
        list.Add(title.TextContent);
        return list.ToArray();
    }
```

but i have problems with author-name

```
var items = document.QuerySelectorAll("a").Where(item => item.ClassName != null && item.ClassName.Contains("eItemProperties_href"));
```

[image]

```
element xpath="//*[@id="PageCenter"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/a" 
selector="#PageCenter > div:nth-child(2) > div.bDetailPage > div.bDetailHeadBlock > div.bBaseInfoColumn > div.bContentColumn > div.bItemCompositionLink > div > div.eItemProperties_list.mHideReadMore > div:nth-child(2) > div.eItemProperties_text > a"
```

1. Pls help me to take book-author and get it by string type.
2. Its possible to take title,description,author-name using by one method?

And get-set like book.title = value, book.description = value, author-name = value

Thank you for taking the time to read.

Comment: have you tried the class selector?   `document.QuerySelectorAll(".eItemProperties_href");`

Comment: thanks for answer. Got error `System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements`
:(

Answer (score 0):

Finally i take author name

```
QuerySelectorAll("div[itemprop*='author']")
```